# Cluster based on random effects, STAN

Tags: mixed-model, clustering, hierarchical-bayesian, mixture-distribution, stan

I have a problem where I measure repeated responses in condition A and in condition B for a set of individuals $i=1,...,n$. I am interested in learning about the effect of the condition in the population, for which fitting a hierarchical model with a random effect for individual would seem reasonable, using a tool such as STAN, with which I'm familiar.

However, it is to be expected that the population is composed of sub-populations, although we don’t know what sub-population each individual belongs to. For example, it is likely that there is a population 1, of individuals with 0 effect of condition, and a population 2, where individuals show an effect of condition, with some variability across individuals. But we don’t know what individual belongs to which.

I am interested in learning about this sub-population structure, and about what sub-populations the individuals belong to. Lets take the example above. It seems to me that we can think of the problem as a mixture of distributions that the individuals come from, one has all its mass on 0 (population 1), and the other one has an effect that we have to estimate, together with its variability (population 2). So, we could set up the problem as estimating the parameters of the mixture distribution, where I would be interested in the mixing probabilities, and the parameters of population 2. I would also be interested in the probability that each individual belongs to one population or the other.

This seems like some kind of clustering or Gaussian Mixture model, but with the GMM applied to random effects, which I haven't seem before. Is this some known type of problem with a name I can look into? Is there some way of setting up this kind of problem in STAN?

Just the problem above would be a good starting point, but I will later want to expand it to work with more complicated mixture distributions, such as 2 populations with different means and variability (not necessarily 0), or even more populations.